# Is performance impact when `getStaticPaths() fetching all posts, which posts total are a million posts?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, next.js, getstaticpaths

```
export async function getStaticPaths() { 
 // Call an external API endpoint to get posts
 const res = await fetch('https://.../posts')
 const posts = await res.json()

 // Get the paths we want to pre-render based on posts
 const paths = posts.map((post) => `/posts/${post.id}`)

 // We'll pre-render only these paths at build time.
 // { fallback: false } means other routes should 404.
 return { paths, fallback: false }
}
```

I'm curious about this thing; in [Next.JS docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages), pre-render would fetch all posts and map it to find data based on the id.

When posts total more than a million posts, is that impact the performance?

Comment: i asked my self the same question. what happen if getStaticPaths should query millions id, database will crash when loading id in one shoot ??

Comment: Have a look at [this discusion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/27574)